# Issue with empty queue running the model on server

Tags: python, queue

I am getting an empty queue issue when I am running the model 'mosaicml/mpt-7b-chat' locally.

Can you please help me in fixing it ? Thanks.

P.S: Logs of the trace are as follows:
Running on local URL: http://127.0.0.1:7860

`To create a public link, set share=True in launch(). history: [['hi', '']]`

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 412,
> in run_predict output = await app.get_blocks().process_api( File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1299, in
> process_api result = await self.call_function( File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1035, in
> call_function prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync( File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in
> run_sync return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread( File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line
> 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread return await future File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line
> 867, in run result = context.run(func, *args) File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 491, in
> async_iteration return next(iterator) File "G:\mpt-7b-chat\app.py",
> line 164, in bot for new_text in streamer: File
> "G:\mpt-7b-chat\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\generation\streamers.py",
> line 195, in next value = self.text_queue.get(timeout=self.timeout)
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\queue.py",
> line 179, in get raise Empty
> _queue.Empty

We dont want any errors and i am running the following code locally:
https://huggingface.co/spaces/mosaicml/mpt-7b-chat/blob/main/app.py